# What can I do with artifacts I don't plan to use?

Tags: nethack

While playing, I often end up owning more artifact weapons than I need. Since I can't `#twoweapon` with two artifact weapons, I really don't need more than one at any time. The wiki page about [artifacts](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Artifact) says that I should not sell them because the shopkeepers don't pay much for them. I would just carry them around, but they are kind of heavy and it's not worth being burdened for a weapon I'm not going to use. Is there anything useful I can do with them besides sticking them in a box somewhere for the rest of the game?

Comment: Please correct "should sell" to "shouldn't sell" otherwise this is exactly contrary to the provided reference.

Answer (score 3):

Many artifacts have special characteristics that make them useful to keep around (for example Greyswandir, Vorpal Blade, and many quest items). Other than that there's nothing too special you can do. If I want to keep one out of my inventory I typically put it in a normal sack on a space on ground that has been engraved with "Elbereth" in fire or lightning to keep them out of the hands of most enemies.

Answer (score 0):

I normally stash them in my Bag of Holding to inflate my score, but if weight is a problem,
I throw them in the water on Medusa level. With the reasoning the only ones who can get them are the ; (sea monster) types and they can not wield them preventing monsters from using them against me.

Comment: Water trolls could still get them; better to stash them in a regular stash IMO.

Comment: now what about lava...